# Inserting a row in cql

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, cql, cqlsh

I have newly created a table where i wanted to insert other column data from another table.
1st i copied other column data in a file and wanted to perform insert operation on each line

My o/p file-

Script i used to insert column data to the newly added table.-

```
    sed "s/' *, *'/' '/g;s/\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\),\(.*\)/INSERT INTO WHERE_USED (prod_id, id,effective_date, revision ,type ) VALUES (/1,/2,/3,/4, 'COMPONENT');s/' '/','/g" whereUsed.cql
```

input file whereUsed.cql -

```
           '4.FIDFLBIDA','1.809853','2015-04-16 12:04:21+0000',''
           'LB333','HK8','2015-05-23 16:20:00+0000',''
           '4.SMA-EI-REC','3.PAS-DYN-LTR','2015-04-10 04:00:00+0000',''
```

Kindly advise

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is good. Did something go wrong?

But you could have used [COPY](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html) statement. This can take CSV as input and insert them efficiently.

Hope this helps!